# scala parallel collection working with too much parallelism

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I try to do filesystem-operation in parallel in Scala using prallel collections. I want to control the number of concurrent operation (e.g. set to 2):

```
import scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport

val filenames = (1 to 50).map(i=> "%03d".format(i)+".dat").par
filenames.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(2))

def doSmth(filename:String) = {
  // simulate expensive FS operation
  new java.io.PrintWriter(s"/home/myuser/$filename") { write("foo"); close }    
  Thread.sleep(2000)
}

filenames.foreach {i => doSmth(i)}
```

Strangely, all files are written at the same time, not 2 files per 2 seconds as expected. If I use `new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(1)`, I get the expected behavior, but not for parallelism > 1

Comment: Your exact same code works on my machine.

Comment: How many processor do you have?

Comment: @KamilBanaszczyk 24

Comment: Did you check on different scala version? Which version do you use?